# Painting zone using wxWidgets and FormBuilder

Tags: c++, wxwidgets, wxformbuilder

I have task to create client (best if it will be possible to build it for Windows & Linux) for some tools and printing hexagonal map.

I chose **wxWidgets** to use for that. I downloaded **WxFormBuilder**, that perfectly helps to create forms and code for them.

But I have to paint hexagonal map somewhere in that form. And I didn't found what item from instrument panel I have to use for that. I can add something like **wxPanel** one by hands in sources that was automatically created for me, but that is bad idea, because after every change from **wxFormBuilder** I will need to parse result again by hands.

I'm new with painting and graphic, but believe there have to be solution for that in **wxFormBuilder**, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

That's the thing about computer programming: at some time you always have to settle down and write some code.  All those applications that promise to write code for you have to be abandoned at some point and you actually have to do some work:  you have reached that point.  ( [Here is a link to more about this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13440487/16582) )

Here is a brief introduction to writing code to paint the application window in wxWidgets, with a minimal sample code: http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/WxDC

Comment: Yes, I feel nothing against writing code :-) I just believe that solution, when I have to rewrite automatically generated .cpp and .h classes every time I change something at FormBuilder is not good solution.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly the problem with form builder type applications.  Because, to maintain anything much more than a toy application, you have to abandon them and write the code yourself.

Comment: +1 for useful links and conceptional view. But I will still wait for reply, if someone knows how to achieve that by FormBuilder.

Comment: I found it is possible dynamically remove wxObject and add another one. So, it is possible to Draw entire UI in FormBuilder, and when you create inherited classes, change objects that have to be upgraded.