# wxWidgets C++ panel is invisible

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I am starting to practise my skills with wxWidgets and I wanted to add some panel with two different texts above this slider, but when I tried, the result is invisible:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(const wxString& title) : wxFrame(NULL, wxID_ANY, title, wxDefaultPosition) {
    wxMenuBar *menubar;
    wxMenu *file;
    menubar = new wxMenuBar;
    file = new wxMenu;
    file->Append(wxID_OPEN, wxT("&Open"));
    menubar->Append(file, wxT("&File"));
    SetMenuBar(menubar);

    wxBoxSizer *vbox = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);
    this->SetSizer(vbox);
    player_widget = new wxWindow(this, wxID_ANY);
    player_widget->SetBackgroundColour(wxColour(wxT("black")));
    vbox->Add(player_widget, 1, wxEXPAND | wxALIGN_TOP);

    wxBoxSizer* bs = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);
    wxPanel* p1 = new wxPanel(this,wxID_ANY,wxDefaultPosition,wxSize(0,20));
    p1->SetSizer(bs);
    p1->Enable(true);
    p1->Show(true);
    vbox->Add(p1,0,wxEXPAND);

    wxStaticText* text1 = new wxStaticText(this,11, "text 1");
    wxStaticText* text2 = new wxStaticText(this,12, "text 2");
    bs->Add(text1);
    bs->Add(text2);

    timeline = new wxSlider(this, myID_TIMELINE, 0, 0, TIMELINE_MAX);
    vbox->Add(timeline, 0, wxEXPAND);

    wxPanel *controlPanel = new wxPanel(this, wxID_ANY);
    wxBoxSizer *hbox = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);
    controlPanel->SetSizer(hbox);
    vbox->Add(controlPanel, 0, wxEXPAND);
    playpause_button = new wxButton(controlPanel, myID_PLAYPAUSE, wxT("Play"));
    stop_button = new wxButton(controlPanel, myID_STOP, wxT("Stop"));
    volume_slider = new wxSlider(controlPanel, myID_VOLUME, VOLUME_MAX, 0, VOLUME_MAX, wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(100, -1));
    hbox->Add(playpause_button);
    hbox->Add(stop_button);
    hbox->AddStretchSpacer();
    hbox->Add(volume_slider);
}
```

Any ideas what I did wrong?

Comment: For designing GUI you might want to consider using wxFormBuilder and then copy and paste the code.

Comment: Or wxGlade or wxCrafter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change parent of `text1` and `text2` to `p1`.

Answer (score 0):

It is simpler to use just one panel that holds everything.

Something like this ( a complete program )

```
#include <wx/wx.h>
#include <wx/app.h>

class cApp : public wxApp
{
public:
    virtual bool OnInit();

};

#define TIMELINE_MAX 100
#define VOLUME_MAX 100

enum {
myID_TIMELINE,
myID_PLAYPAUSE,
myID_STOP,
myID_VOLUME
};

class cFrame: public wxFrame
{

    wxWindow * player_widget;
    wxSlider * timeline;
    wxSlider * volume_slider;
    wxButton * playpause_button;
    wxButton * stop_button;

public:
    cFrame(wxFrame *frame, const wxString& title)
        : wxFrame(frame, -1, title, wxPoint(-1,-1),wxSize(600,600))
        {
    wxMenuBar *menubar;
    wxMenu *file;
    menubar = new wxMenuBar;
    file = new wxMenu;
    file->Append(wxID_OPEN, wxT("&Open"));
    menubar->Append(file, wxT("&File"));
    SetMenuBar(menubar);

    // define one panel to hold everything
    // make it big enough to fill the frame
    wxPanel* p1 = new wxPanel(this,wxID_ANY, wxPoint(-1,-1),wxSize(600,600) );

    // top level sizer to hold everything
    wxBoxSizer *vbox = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);

    // add window widget at top
    player_widget = new wxWindow(p1, wxID_ANY);
    player_widget->SetBackgroundColour(wxColour(wxT("black")));
    vbox->Add(player_widget, 1, wxEXPAND | wxALIGN_TOP);

    // add some texts in a horizontal row
    wxBoxSizer* bs = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);
    wxStaticText* text1 = new wxStaticText(p1,11, "text 1");
    wxStaticText* text2 = new wxStaticText(p1,12, "text 2");
    bs->Add(text1);
    bs->Add(text2);

    // add texts just below window widget
    vbox->Add( bs );

    // add slider below texts
    timeline = new wxSlider(this, myID_TIMELINE, 0, 0, TIMELINE_MAX);
    vbox->Add(timeline, 0, wxEXPAND);

    // some more controls in a row
    wxBoxSizer *hbox = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);
    playpause_button = new wxButton(p1, myID_PLAYPAUSE, wxT("Play"));
    stop_button = new wxButton(p1, myID_STOP, wxT("Stop"));
    volume_slider = new wxSlider(p1, myID_VOLUME, VOLUME_MAX,
           0, VOLUME_MAX, wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(100, -1));
    hbox->Add(playpause_button);
    hbox->Add(stop_button);
    hbox->AddStretchSpacer();
    hbox->Add(volume_slider);

    // add controls below big slider
    vbox->Add( hbox );

    // make everything happen
    SetSizer(vbox);
        }
};

IMPLEMENT_APP(cApp);

bool cApp::OnInit()
{
    cFrame* frame = new cFrame(0L, _("wx Starter"));
    frame->Show();

    return true;
}
```

This gives:

[image]

Here's the thing about computer programming: at some time you always have to settle down and write some code.  All those applications, like wxFormBuilder, that promise to write code for you have to be abandoned at some point and you actually have to do some work ( [Here is a link to more about this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13440487/16582) )

Comment: you are correct. However for a person that just now comes to wx framework and wants to learn and understand it, it is easier to use a tool and then look at the code produced, then write sizer code from scratch from Day 1. Wouldn't you agree?

Comment: Sorry, I do not agree.  Looking at the code produced by automatic code generators is not helpful.  The auto-code is designed to be easily maintained by the code generator - not for teaching purposes.  A novice coder is better off looking at sample code, written by human beings and designed to be learned from by human beings.